# Help me solve this exponential function problem...

Tags: exponential-function

The temperature of a cooling liquid over time can be modelled by the exponential function

$$T(x)=60\left(\frac12\right)^\frac x{30}+20$$

where T(*x*) is the temperature, in degrees Celsius, and *x* is the elapsed time, in minutes.

Question I am trying to answer: Determine how long it takes for the temperature to reach 28 degrees Celsius.

I can't figure out how to isolate *x*. Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Comment: if you want to solve the equation

Answer (score 1):

Apply $\ln(x^y) = y \ln(x)$:
\begin{align}
T(x) &= 60 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\large x/30} + 20 \iff \\
\ln\left(\frac{T - 20}{60}\right) &= \frac{x}{30} \ln \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \iff \\
x(T) &= \cdots 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

if you want to solve the equation
$28=60\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x/30}+20$

Simplify the above equation we get
$\frac{8}{60}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x/30}$

Taking the logarithm on both sides we obtain
$\ln\left(\frac{2}{15}\right)=\frac{x}{30}\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Now i am sure you can isolate $x$ ?